# How to use current location with Yelp API

Tags: ios, swift, yelp-fusion-api

I am creating a yelp API app, but I am having trouble with my current location code. It seems the problem is my call to the API is happening before my values of Longitude and latitude are set, but I don't know how to rearrange my code to fix this issue. I have attached my code below lmk if you see anything I can do.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var venuesTableView: UITableView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var long: Double = 0.0
    var lat: Double = 0.0
    
    
    /// Central Park, NYC coordinates
    let CPLatitude: Double = 40.782483
    let CPLongitude: Double = -73.963540
    
    // Menlo Park, California Coordinates
    let MPLatitude: Double = 37.4539910200113
    let MPLongitude: Double = -122.19097843112596
    
    var venues: [Venue] = []
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else{return}
        
        
        long = locValue.longitude
        lat = locValue.latitude
        
        print(long)
        print(lat)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        venuesTableView.delegate = self
        venuesTableView.dataSource = self
        venuesTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        venuesTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
        retrieveVenues(latitude: lat, longitude: long, category: "eventservices",
                       limit: 20, sortBy: "distance", locale: "en_US") { (response, error) in
            
            if let response = response {
                self.venues = response
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.venuesTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            print("Does this work?")
            print(self.long)
            print(self.lat)
        }
        
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func userCurrentLocation(){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function for the api call.

```
private func getVenues() {
    retrieveVenues(latitude: lat, longitude: long, category: "eventservices",
                   limit: 20, sortBy: "distance", locale: "en_US") { (response, error) in
        
        if let response = response {
            self.venues = response
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.venuesTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        print("Does this work?")
        print(self.long)
        print(self.lat)
    }
}
```

Then call this from the delegate method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations
    locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else{return}
            
    long = locValue.longitude
    lat = locValue.latitude
    
    getVenues()
}
```